# border styling in css3 unusual design

Tags: css, border

My goal is to get such effects with borders in pure css. I want to ask You is it possible (or I have to use images)? Do I have to use so kind of span attribute or a outline or something else? Maybe You know were I can find tutorial how to do it?

[image: first border]

[image: second]

[image: third]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility that doesn't use borders, but is pure CSS is some wacky work with pseudo elements.

For example:

```
p:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

You can see the demo here: http://jsbin.com/iduvoj/1/edit

Here is another demo of your last example: http://jsbin.com/igotul/1/edit

Now this depends on a few things, like how many elements you'll be stacking, whether or not your paragraph can have a solid background color, etc. But there's a chance it'll work.

It also only depends on `:before` and `:after` which are fairly well supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=before

Comment: Works great! Love it! Thanky You @mookamafoob.

Answer (score 1):

This will be tricky.

The best I can offer you using borders is CSS `border-image`, which will indeed allow you to design pretty much arbitrary border designs. You can read more about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).

It has the advantage that it's designed to handle stretching images across the length of the border and having separate images for each side and corners, etc, as necessary so it's very flexible.

I won't give an example beyond those on the MDN page linked above, because the CSS code itself is relatively simple; the main thing you'll need to get it working will be the actual images, and that's something you'll need to provide yourself.

However the main problem you'll have with `border-image` is browser support. It's a relatively recent addition to CSS, and some fairly modern browsers don't support it. That includes IE10. Depending on what you need, that may scupper this as a solution.

So the alternative solution that will work better cross-browser is simply to have the borders defined as background images. This is fairly obvious, and actually works quite well. If the boxes can vary in height a lot then you may get issues with scaling, but this can be avoided by using multiple background images.

Hope that helps.